# Complexity of solving a Diophantine equation with potential solutions

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity

Say I have an equation, given as

13x + 5y = M, where M is given each time.

Evidently this is a diophantine equation and could take a long time to solve depending on the case.  However, a reading told me that if we have a set of unique integer "possible solutions" of size k for X and Y stored in a Binary search tree (meaning the correct values for X and Y are contained in there somewhere), we can compute the solution pair (x, y) to the equation in O(k) time.

Now, I'm stuck on this logic because I do not see how storing elements in this data structure helps us or prevents us from having to plug in each of the k elements for X or Y, solve for the other variable, and check if the data structure contains that variable.  The only thing I can think of would be somehow keeping two pointers to move along the tree, but that doesn't seem feasible.
Could someone explain the reasoning behind this logic?

Comment: "a reading" -- what reading?

Answer (score 1):

Solving [linear Diophantine equations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diophantine_equation#Linear_Diophantine_equations) (which is what you seem to be thinking of) is trivial and requires nothing more than the extended Euclidian algorithm. On the other hand, the successful resolution of [Hilbert's tenth problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert%27s_tenth_problem) implies that there is no algorithm which is able to solve arbitrary Diophantine equations.

There is a vast gap between linear and arbitrary. Perhaps you can focus your question on the type of equation you are interested in.

Comment: I'm aware of Hilbert's tenth problem, but in this particular question it seems to suggest that given a set of possible solutions, it is possible to pick out the correct values for X and Y in linear time.  It's the binary search tree that is confusing to me, as I don't quite understand its purpose.

Comment: I'm not quite sure what they are getting at. The extended euclidean algorithm gives you one solution in better than linear time (or tells you that no solution exists), at which stage you have a 1-parameter family of all solutions, with a formula that can be evaluated in `O(1)` time. Perhaps they are talking about satisfying some side constraint that will pick out one of the possible solutions out of the infinitely many. Your use of the singular "the" in "the correct values" seems to suggest that reading.